# Нужны ли кавычки в названиях мусорных полигонов?

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Названия военных полигонов (как и военных баз, аэродромов) пишутся без кавычек.

Распространяется ли это правило на мусорные полигоны?

На мой взгляд, нет, потому что **полигон твердых бытовых отходов «Кучино»** – не то же самое, что ракетный военный полигон Капустин Яр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно предположить следующее:

1) Полигон ТБО – это ФИРМА (предприятие, организация), поэтому название пишется в кавычках.

"В представлении многих обывателей полигон твердых бытовых отходов – это обычная городская свалка. Однако, это мнение является ошибочным. Полигон твердых бытовых отходов является довольно сложным инженерным сооружением, которое не только обеспечивает складирование мусора, но и выполняет другие природоохранные задачи – защищает почвы, подземные воды и воздух от вредного влияния продуктов разложения".
[**Полигон твердых бытовых отходов – что это такое?**](http://www.eco-industriya.ru/poligon-tverdyh-bytovyh-othodov-chto-eto-takoe/)

2) Военный полигон –  это "большой, специально оборудованный УЧАСТОК для испытания различных видов оружия, боевых средств и техники, а также для проведения боевых учений". Поэтому название полигона по своей форме соответствует названиям ТЕРРИТОРИАЛЬНЫХ административных единиц (городов, поселений и т.д.).